# Installing virtualenvwrapper on macOS Sierra - "-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory" error

Tags: macos, python

I'm a bit of a newbie to Python and definitely to virtual environments and Django. I want to install Django but it first recommends a `virtualenv` / `virtualenvwrapper`. A video I am watching recommends installing `virtualenvwrapper` so I just tried this, following these instructions:

https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#basic-installation
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101559/terminal-where-is-the-shell-start-up-file

I first ran

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

which seemed to work fine. It generated some messages, ending with:

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/ba/f95e3ec83f93919b1437028e989cf3fa5ff4f5cae4a1f62255f71deddb5b/pbr-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 5.3MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /Users/rishi/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, pbr, stevedore, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper
Successfully installed pbr-4.0.2 stevedore-1.28.0 virtualenv-15.2.0 virtualenv-clone-0.3.0 virtualenvwrapper-4.8.2
```

I then had to follow the "shell startup" guidelines which mentioned adding these lines to be shell startup file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I did this. Once I run `$ source ~/.bash_profile` on terminal, I am presented with this error:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory`

After searching online, a forum post recommended that I run:

`which virtualenvwrapper.sh`

and this gives me the result:

`/Users/rishi/anaconda3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Note I have Anaconda installed for some (previous) learning. I now want to install/learn Django.

Searching online, one person recommended to copy the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` from the one directory to the `/usr/local/bin/` directory. It also seems like I should have done this with `sudo` - i.e. should I have run the following?

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I'm super confused - I never was good with server/installing stuff so I'd really appreciate guidance on how/what to install correctly in order to get my virtual environment working, and then hopefully I can use Django.

Perhaps you may recommend

1. just copying the Anaconda `virtualenvwrapper.sh`  file as suggested?
2. Or if I should install again using `sudo` then please let me know how to uninstall virtualenvwrapper (that I just installed) so I can re-install it,

or please simply let me know the steps I should follow as I don't want to mess anything up, if I haven't already!

**UPDATE**

I copied the file from Anandonda to the main folder as explained above, and then ran this. The following messages were generated, and now I seem to be good, I can use the `workon` command for example.

```
Rishi:bin rishi$ source ~/.bash_profile
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/premkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/postmkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/initialize
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/premkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/postmkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/prermvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/postrmvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/rishi/.virtualenvs/get_env_details
```

Comment: @klanomath I understand what you are saying, but before I do it - do you currently have Anaconda? If so do both Django and Anaconda work  in harmony?

Comment: I have some VMs with Anaconda installed but I don't develop apps actively with it. If you want to learn more than Django (i.e. use other Anaconda packages) Anaconda is probably OK.

Comment: if your using python installed with Anacoda, you may want to install virtual environments following the directions in the Anaconda docs. Very easy and straight forward.

Comment: an equally good method is to google "anaconda virtual environment"

Comment: To use MAMP/MAMP Pro's mysql you have to add proper paths to its binaries (i.e. /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin). Additionally you'd have to install some [connectors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes)

Comment: @klanomath thank you so much - working through your comments, I managed to install Django as mentioned on the other comments. It turns out this was an Anaconda thing, but before this post I think Anaconda resides on my PC "on the side" as I presumed I would want it to be, but it seems I can totally rely on it. I'll try the Django route through Anaconda and see if I can manage.

Comment: @jmh - Thank you very much! Yes indeed I just tried this and Django is now installed :) Please let me know if you have a reply to the below as to how to preview it on a web browser. For example Jupyter doesn't sound right to me since it's more data analysis based, from my (newbie) opinion.

Comment: @klanomath Thanks. MAMP is not super important to me, but it is installed on my laptop. What would you recommend is a straightforward way to review my Anaconda Django web app on a browser (localhost) as I build it? Would you say to use MAMP (as per your above comment, with connectors) or is there a more straightforward approach?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mix of pythons on your machine. I would stick to one.

In this case I would stick to anaconda.

SO edit your path so that anaconda is first on the path before /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin

Test by running

```
 which python
```

You should get

```
/Users/mark/anaconda3/bin/python
```

If a 2 rather than 3 you have python2,7 and I would switch to 3.

You can now use virtulenv etc as they are part of python 3.6 (the current 3.x version) see the python docs You should use venv now not what your tutorial shows https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

However as you are using anaconda you can use conda insteaf of venv, You will find most things already installed (I use conda as it provides prebuilt C libraries when needed, pip etc can be more complex and also could require Xcode) https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html The django install is at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/django

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually installed it using `pip` as mentioned here: http://felipegalvao.com.br/blog/2017/01/03/creating-development-environments-and-installing-django-with-anaconda/ and it all works fine now. From the comments above with the others, I also realized changed my mind from treating Anaconda as a 'side' installation of Python, to treating it as my 'main' python. The environment I'm using (see link) is from `conda` which works great too.

Comment: The problem with random blogs on the web unless they are part of a curated series they are not necessarily the best practice. As noted in the comments conda not pip is the best way and the blog author admits he does not know whey he had to use pip. StackExchnage etc is better as answers are voted on or edited. Don't use a single blog unless you can crossreference it to another saying the same thing or else it is a trusted site.

Comment: that's a great point, thank you, I didn't realize it. In my situation, what would you do? Perhaps I can delete my virtual environment with pip/django, and then create a new virtual enviroment with `conda` to be safe? I also want to install https://anaconda.org/anaconda/coverage into my environment, but I'm wary to use `conda` on my current environment where django was installed with `pip` (within Anaconda)

Comment: If you want anaconda as your main python I would put it on the path before and use conda for environment and start from scratch. (You don't have to but if you want to manage both you need to have a better unbderstanding of how they interact) conda will create new environments